# Code not working as expected. Using ArrayList and for loop in my Selenium Webdriver Java code

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, arraylist

So I have recently started my work on Selenium Webdriver using Java. Below is the code:

```
List<LineDashboardDetails> LineDashboardDetailList = new ArrayList<LineDashboardDetails>();

        LineDashboardDetails objLineDetail = new LineDashboardDetails();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < lineUITextList.size(); i++) {
            objLineDetail.lineName=lineUITextList.get(i);
            objLineDetail.machineNames = machineUITextList.get(i).toString();
            LineDashboardDetailList.add(objLineDetail);
        }

        System.out.println(LineDashboardDetailList);
```

I have created a lineUITextList ArrayList of String. This array will always have only 1 value in it. So the issue is above for loop does not work. The loop only executes once and comes out to print the LineDashboardDetailList. The machineUITextList array has around 5-6 values in it. My expectation is to have LineDashboardDetailList such that the lineUITextList common value is paired with each new value of machineUITextList.
For example if lineUITextList= {"Noun"}
machineUITextList= {"Pen","Box","Note","Scale"}

So my list i.e LineDashboardDetailList should give me output as:
Noun,Pen
Noun,Box
Noun,Note
Noun,Scale

I am using LineDashboardDetailList List further in my code.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your code loop is about the size of `lineUITextList`, which is 1. Why did you assume it will ignore your code and iterate over `machineUITextList` instead?  Also, you really should read [Why does my ArrayList contain N copies of the last item added to the list?](//stackoverflow.com/q/19843506).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not totally sure what you are trying to achive. Personally, I would use a java.util.Map to associate each value of the `lineUITextList` with the list of values of `machineUITextList`.
However, to help you in achiving your goal, first of all, I would design the `LineDashboardDetails` class in order to maintain the single value of the `lineUITextList`, along with the list of `machineUITextList`, so as you can combine them by using a specific method. That has lots of advantages in terms of encapsulation, distribution of responsabilities, etc.., plus you can always reuse for other purposes.
The function to combine the values can be easily implemented by taking advantages of Java stream and built-in functional interfaces.
Here is the code of the `LineDashboardDetails` class:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class LineDashboardDetails {
    private String lineName;
    private List<String> machineNames;


    public String getLineName() {
        return lineName;
    }

    public void setLineName(String lineName) {
        this.lineName = lineName;
    }

    public List<String> getMachineNames() {
        return new ArrayList<>(machineNames);
    }

    public void setMachineNames(List<String> machineNames) {
        this.machineNames = new ArrayList<>(machineNames);
    }

    public List<String> getCombinedList() {
        return  machineNames.stream()
                            .map(s -> lineName + "," + s)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Here is instead the code that you tried to implement, which uses the class above and combine the two list, and finally prints out the list of values as you expect. You can see, I prepared two simple list in the main method, but you can actually generalize it in relation to your own needs:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class SeleniumWebdriverListTest {

    public List<LineDashboardDetails> combineUITextListWithMachineUIText(List<String> lineUITextList,
                                                                         List<String> machineUITextList) {

        List<LineDashboardDetails> lineDashboardDetailList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (String lineUIText : lineUITextList) {
            LineDashboardDetails objLineDetail = new LineDashboardDetails();
            objLineDetail.setLineName(lineUIText);
            objLineDetail.setMachineNames(machineUITextList);
            lineDashboardDetailList.add(objLineDetail);
        }

        return lineDashboardDetailList;
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> lineUITextList = new ArrayList<>();
        lineUITextList.add("Noun");

        List<String> machineUITextList = new ArrayList<>();
        machineUITextList.add("Pen");
        machineUITextList.add("Box");
        machineUITextList.add("Note");
        machineUITextList.add("Scale");

        List<LineDashboardDetails> lineDashboardDetailList =
                new SeleniumWebdriverListTest().combineUITextListWithMachineUIText(
                        lineUITextList, machineUITextList);

        lineDashboardDetailList.stream()
                               .map(s -> s.getCombinedList())
                               .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

I could have used Java streams and a specific lamba expression to implement the `combineUITextListWithMachineUIText` method as well, but I kept somehow your original version to let you understand my idea of implementation around your code.
Here is the output I get:

```
[Noun,Pen, Noun,Box, Noun,Note, Noun,Scale]
```

Feel free to ask for any clarification.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your code with getter and setter. But the line to getMachineNames is giving me error. Do you think it should be List<String>? Also if I use the same code as is then error shown is 'The method copyAll(List<String>) is undefined for the type List'

Comment: That dipends on the Java version you are using. I use JDK 11, and the method List.copyOf was introduced since Java 10. I am not getting any error, but actually method getMachineNames might cause some warning as I forgot to put List<String> instead of simply List, which is interpreted by the compiler as a List of Object. I am going to change the method in the answer. However, to follow security guidelines, I would remove the method at all.

Comment: I've just fixed the methods in LineDashboardDetails. That works with Java 8 as well. Have a look and let me know if you need for any further help.

Comment: No news so far. Did you even try the code above? If it doesn't work (only by hypothesis) I could fix it. On the other hand, if my proposal solution solves your issues and meets your purposes, you should accept the answer and, possibly upvote it, so in the future my answer can help other developers who asks for similar question. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, This is just a piece of in between code, I am trying to figure out if the entire scenario of my functionality is working fine or not. There are still some issues. I am trying to fix currently.

Comment: My intention was not to write all your application. You asked for a specific issue and I provided you an answer which should help you to fix it. If you are happy with that answer, related to the specific question, you should just accept the answer and upvote, so people who might have the same issue in the feature will receive a help as well by the same answer. However, in case you have some more issues, please just submit a new question and we (the community) will be happy to help